# Android\Java CountDownLatch block handle HTTP response

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a thread which send request to server and process request from the server.

I have a trouble, when i use **CountDownLatch** in my thread.

- What the trouble?

When i send request i do `latch.await()` later, and try to `latch.countDown()` after request was obtained from the server but i think when response come it was not called in listener because main thread is blocked.
I will explain my problem with picture below :

[image]

So how can i fix this or maybe exist another way to handle this problem?

Comment: Skip the picture. Give us the code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, blocking the Main thread is a really bad practice because your UI becomes unresponsive and you should definitely try to avoid that.

A simple solution might be to use an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and if you read the documentation it does handle the execution flow for you, passing the results from a worker thread to the UI one.

If you don't need a result that affects directly your device UI, you can use an [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html).

There are definitely other solutions available(even with Latches) but a general rule should be:

- avoid heavy operations on the Main Thread
- avoid blocking operations on the Main Thread

Comment: I use an AsyncTask. And that's strange behavior. Calling request is processed in doInBackground method.